# Solution for wired and cable home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have quite a simple home network setup, but can´t seem to find out how to make it work. What I have is this: A main router/modem located in a small "shed", with a static IP from my ISP. This router/modem has access to a panel with rj45 outlets that covers most of my home. If I connect my pc to an outlet, let´s say on the second floor, I get around 300Mbps - which is what I pay for. This router/modem also has a wireless feature. But the problem is that it only covers most of the first floor, and I would like Wi-Fi coverage all over my home of course.

The optimal scenario for me would be to plug in my old router on the second floor (and another one I bought for the first floor) to any of the rj45 outlets, so it can extend the wireless coverage (with the same SSID), and communicate with the main router/modem via the LAN connection. Furthermore, I would like my phone/clients to always choose the strongest signal, so my phone doesent hold grasp of that bad router/modem wireless connection even though I´m stand right next to the second router. The solution I imagine:

[House layout with routers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsL5r.jpg)

I´ve read about Access points, bridging and WDS. My old router only supports WDS which, as I understand, only connects to the main router via wireless. So how is this possible? Do I need to buy another type of networking equipment to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quick and dirty best bet is to plug in your routers to the outlets in the locations you want, but to ensure they are set to bridge/AP mode. If not, you'll be creating new (and possibly conflicting) networks unless you change up the IPs.

Your "best practice" best bet is to set up a switch with your communication shed and hook that up to your ethernet panel and router. Then set up some APs/mesh devices as Jacob Mueller suggested.

Ensuring your device only chooses the strongest signal may prove to be a small challenge. Your average AP/router probably won't include session handoffs, especially if they're from different vendors/generations of hardware. If you don't go the AP/mesh device route, the best you'll probably be able to do is manually set the power levels or use a directional antenna.

Comment: Regarding google Mesh, please see my comment to Jacob Mueller. 
But ok, it seems like I have to invest in another mesh technology, to make sure that my phone/clients always chooses the strongest signal AND the AP´s are using ethernet to communicate to each other with?

Comment: You can get by (mostly) with your average Joe routers configured in AP mode. It just won't hand off as seamlessly/may disconnect. If you go the actual AP/mesh route, then yes, you will want to ensure they're hooked up to a switch and not different networks through a router.

Comment: Ok, so in my situation, why would I choose an expensive mesh solution when I can have AP´s hooked up to ethernet? Is the only drawback that the client looses connectivity for a couple of seconds when it switches AP?
So I guess my best bet is, like you say, find some average joe routers that supports bridge/AP mode, and hook them up.

Comment: If you're OK with that drawback (I would, personally), then there's no major reason you should go for the mesh solution. I'd get the inexpensive APs and do some basic configuration/power level adjustments

Answer (score 1):

While there's no reason you couldn't implement the scenario you outline, you're really implementing technology using an old paradigm. The new hotness in home wireless networking is 'mesh' wireless. There are a number of new solutions, but google has a solution called "google wifi" that works pretty well. Rather than have a small number of strongly powered APs, you have a larger number of lightly powered devices that handle that seamless handoffs of your devices. It sounds like your problem could be solved by that type of hardware.

Comment: I´ve already tried Google mesh. But because there is an ongoing error in an update last year, which in short means that the puck prefer´s bad Wi-Fi over strong ethernet, I have returned it. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleWiFi/comments/9uo2lh/google_wifi_no_longer_will_use_ethernet/
https://support.google.com/wifi/thread/265031?hl=en